# Same branch in all git repos at one go

Tags: git, github

I have a github organisation with 10 repos within the organization. for every release, I need to go to each one and create the same branch based on their latest commit on all repos. is there any way I can do this once ?
If submodules is an option, how to achieve this using submodules?

Comment: Why use branch for release, not tags?

Comment: What I meant is for every new work to start, we have to create new branches and I need to manually go and create IN each of the repos .

Comment: Are you looking for a way to write a script, which would, in one call, create a new branch with a specific name in each of the 10 repositories ?

Comment: yes exacly. whenever I need a branch, I need that to be created in all repos.

Answer (score -1):

Git submodules enable you to preserve one git repository as a subfolder of another.

so submodules will not help you in this case.

You can use PowerShell to automate the process.

Comment: can you give me some hint?